# Location and size of pgf plot axis in a tikzpicture - with tikz positioning library?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning

This could be a second part to [Positioning pgfplots axis in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167379/positioning-pgfplots-axis-in-tikzpicture) , I guess ; consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{nn} = [rectangle,draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2cm,line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{ni} = [rectangle,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,draw=red]

\node[nn,anchor=south west] (nodeOne) at (0,0) {One};
\node[nn,rotate=90] (nodeTwo) [right=6cm of nodeOne] {\emph{Two}} ;

\node[ni]
  (nodeIndicator) [above right=0cm and 1.5cm of nodeOne] {} ;

\begin{axis}[%
%   at={(nodeOne)}, % passes
%   at={above right=0cm and 1.5cm of nodeOne}, % tikz Error: Cannot parse this coordinate.
  above right=0cm and 1.5cm of nodeOne, % passes, but wrong?
  inner sep=0pt,
  width=4cm,
  height=3cm,
]
\addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) } ;
\end{axis}

% graphical rulers in tikz - via grid:

% x ruler:
\draw[red] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] ({current bounding box.east|-(0cm,0.5cm);});
% y ruler:
\draw[red] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] ({current bounding box.north-|(0.5cm,0cm);});


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following output:

[image: test01.png]

It can be seen that the syntax `above right=0cm and 1.5cm of nodeOne`, due to the `positioning` library, works as expected in the case of `nodeIndicator`.

However, if I use the same construct in the `{axis}` environment, it is completely ignored! So my question is - how can I use `positioning` library syntax with the pgfplots `{axis}` environment?

Second - I just noticed this on this MWE - you can see that even if I specify `width=4cm,height=3cm` for the `{axis}` environment, the rendered plot is much smaller (that's why the rulers are added). What sort of size should the `width` and `height` refer to in the case of `{axis}` environment? (It's not the inner plot; neither it is inner plot+axes tick labels ... also related here: [How to properly scale a TikZ/PGF picture which has a `\begin{axis}...\end{axis}`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17438/how-to-properly-scale-a-tikz-pgf-picture-which-has-a-beginaxis-endaxis))

Comment: About the size issue: By default, PGFPlots leaves space for the axis labels, that's why the plot area is smaller than the specified `width` and `height`. If you don't want that (because you don't have labels, for instance), use `scale only axis`.

Comment: 1cm gets translated at 28.3pt which is the same as 28.3 to pgfmath.  So it could just be off the page.

Comment: Anyway, in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172814/tikz-stacked-bar-chart-with-text/172847#172847 I would name coordinates before \end{axis} and use them after.

Comment: Here is some insight regarding the "why": it seems that the positioning library is plain incompatible with the placement of `pgfplots` axes (a `pgfplots` axis is a PGF node, not a TikZ node -- and the positioning library affects only TikZ nodes). Please refer to the answer of @ Torbjørn for a suitable replacement.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why that syntax doesn't work, but you can use the syntax of the `calc` library. While not exactly the same, it does allow you to place axes relative to other nodes/coordinates. Note that the default `anchor` for the `axis` is `south west`, change that if desirable.

In the code below I used `at={($(nodeOne)+(0cm,1.5cm)$)}`. When no anchor for the node is supplied (e.g. `nodeOne.west`), the `center` anchor is assumed. As you can see, the lower left corner (`anchor=south west`) of the `axis` is 1.5cm above the center of `nodeOne`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\pagecolor{yellow!15}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{
nn/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=4cm,minimum height=2cm,line width=1pt,inner sep=0pt},
ni/.style={rectangle,draw,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm,draw=red}}

\node[nn,anchor=south west] (nodeOne) at (0,0) {One};
\node[nn,rotate=90] (nodeTwo) [right=6cm of nodeOne] {\emph{Two}} ;

\node[ni]
  (nodeIndicator) [above right=0cm and 1.5cm of nodeOne] {} ;

\begin{axis}[%
  at={($(nodeOne)+(0cm,1.5cm)$)},
  anchor=south west,
  inner sep=0pt,
  width=4cm,
  height=3cm,
  scale only axis
]
\addplot coordinates { (0,0) (1,1) } ;
\end{axis}

% graphical rulers in tikz - via grid:

% x ruler:
\draw[red] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] ({current bounding box.east|-(0cm,0.5cm);});
% y ruler:
\draw[red] (0,0) grid[step=1cm] ({current bounding box.north-|(0.5cm,0cm);});


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```