# Conflict tikzscale and matrix group plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-matrix, groupplots, tikzscale

I want two axis environments next to each other in one figure environment. I want them to be vertically aligned and scaled to the width of the text. I am trying to achieve this by means of the `tikzscale` package and `\matrix` group plot capability of `pgfplots`, but I get an error.

Compiling

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

\begin{document}
    \includegraphics{tikzpicture.tikz}
\end{document}
```

where `tikzpicture.tikz` has the content

```
\begin{tikzpicture} % THIS EXAMPLE STEMS FROM PAGE 288 FROM THE PGFPLOTS MANUAL REVISION 1.8 (2013/03/17).
    \matrix
    {
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x};
        \end{axis}
        &
        % differently large labels are aligned automatically:
        \begin{axis}
        [
            ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$},
            ylabel style={font=\Huge}
        ]
            \addplot {x^2};
        \end{axis}
        \\
        %
        \begin{axis}
        [
            xlabel=$x$,
            xlabel style={font=\Huge}
        ]
            \addplot {x^3};
        \end{axis}
        &
        \begin{axis}
            \addplot {x^4};
        \end{axis}
        \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

works just fine. But when I then try to scale the (too wide) picture with the `tikzscale` package by changing

```
\includegraphics{tikzpicture.tikz}
```

to

```
\includegraphics[witdh=\textwidth]{tikzpicture.tikz}
```

I get the error

```
./tikzpicture.tikz:6: Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot width `-100.58875pt' is too small. This cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your width..
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why not using `\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}` from pgfplots-package? ;)

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the results you are looking for I would work directly on the `axis` environments without using `\matrix`.  The advantage is that you control directly the dimensions and positions of your graphs.  Furthermore, you have the possibility to scale things globally at the end through the `tikzpicture` options.

[image]

The code is below.  The coordinates of the lower-left corner of `axis` are controlled by the key=value `at={(a, b)}`.  You may find Torbjørn T.'s answer at [Positioning pgfplots axis in tikzpicture](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167379/positioning-pgfplots-axis-in-tikzpicture) useful.

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[top=105pt, bottom=75pt, left=75pt, right=75pt]{geometry}
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{45pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{flushleft}
  \Large\bfseries Scaling \verb|axis|
\end{flushleft}


\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.05, every node/.style={scale=1}]

    \begin{axis}[width=0.43\textwidth, height=6cm, at={(0, 0)}]
      \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
    
    \begin{axis}[ylabel={$f(x)=x^2$}, ylabel style={font=\Huge},
      width=0.45\textwidth, height=6cm, at={(0.5\textwidth, 0)}]
      \addplot {x^2};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, xlabel style={font=\Huge},
      width=0.43\textwidth, height=6cm, at={(0, -6 cm)}]
      \addplot {x^3};
    \end{axis}

    \begin{axis}[width=0.45\textwidth, height=6cm,
      at={(0.5\textwidth, -6 cm)}]
      \addplot {x^4};
    \end{axis}
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```