# Error `tikzscale` package when scaling a figure, containing two axis environments next to each other, to the text width

Tags: pgfplots, floats, scaling, tikzscale

I have a `figure` environment with which I depict two `pgfplots` `axis` environments next to each other. I want to scale the figure such that it uses the full `\textwidth`. I attempt to do so by means of the `tikzscale` package. I however, get the error

```
! Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot width `-144.19234pt' is too small. This cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels. Sorry, label sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your width..
```

while there is plenty of room to scale the figure.

The minimum working example is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{float} % Improved interface for floating objects.
\usepackage{lipsum} % For test purposes.
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{tikzscale}

% TikZ libraries.
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzset{external/system call={lualatex -shell-escape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"}}
\tikzexternalize
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1]
    \begin{figure}[H]
        \begin{center}
            \tikzset{external/remake next}
            \tikzsetnextfilename{\currfiledir tikzpicture}
            \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{\currfiledir tikzpicture.tikz}
        \end{center}
        \caption{Test caption.}
    \end{figure}
    \lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

The content of `tikzpicture.tikz` is represented by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \begin{loglogaxis}
    [
        name=plot_left,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$
    ]

        \addplot {x};

    \end{loglogaxis}

    \begin{loglogaxis}
    [
        name=plot_right,
        at={($(plot_left.outer east)+(5mm,0)$)},
        anchor=outer west,
        legend style=
        {
            at={(1,1)},
            anchor=north west,
            draw=none,
            fill=none
        },
        legend cell align=left,
        xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$
    ]

        \addplot {x};

        \legend
        {
            $l_1$
        }

    \end{loglogaxis}

    \draw[dashed,line width=0pt] (plot_left.outer south west) rectangle (plot_left.outer north east);
    \draw[dashed,line width=0pt] (plot_right.outer south west) rectangle (plot_right.outer north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: Is the fact that externalization is involved here relevant to the problem? If not, I'm tempted to close as a duplicate of your other question. (I can always delete my answer there, if you feel that it reduces the chance of a better one.) Or perhaps you can specify that my suggestion is *not* an alternative due to the problems you mentioned.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. No the externalization has nothing to with it. The difference with the question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/230974/conflict-tikzscale-and-matrix-group-plot?noredirect=1#comment650030_230974 is that in this example, I do not use `\matrix`. But besides that, the problem is the same: scaling a figure to the `\texwidth`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that, but I dont't think that matters at all to be honest. You get exactly the same error as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Indeed. Any suggestions for a solution? I unfortunately don't seem to be getting a response. Surprises me a bit, since I'm sure a lot of people have the same problem.

Comment: Nothing very good, no. You might want to contact the author of `tikzscale` and tell him of this, perhaps he can find a fix for the package.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I already did on 20-03-2015. Unfortunately, I did not get a response from him. I'll send him a reminder.

Comment: Some years have passed and I'm running into the same issue in the last days. Have you found any solution for that?

I've found out, that using `at=(plot2.right of south east),` and `anchor=left of south west,` reduce the error probability.
Furthermore scaling the `height` (if necessary in combination with `axisratio`) instead of the `width` reduces the error as well. But this way you cannot scale figures to the width of the line etc.
Any help appreciated!